# Why isn't my every label/.style showing tiny nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I can't figure out what mistake I am making, but I'm unable to set the global font size to, say, `\tiny` for the label nodes.  I tried `every label/.style={font=\tiny}`.  It seems to be working for the axis labels but not for the label node. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
  standard/.style={%Axis format configuration
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every label/.style={font=\tiny},
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east},
   every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black}}
    }
 }
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={-1,0,1},
      xticklabels={-1, 0, 1},
      extra x tick style={
      xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south}},
      xmin=-4,xmax=4, ytick={\empty}, yticklabels={}, 
      ymin=-2, ymax=2, axis on top,
      enlarge y limits=0.35,
      width=6cm,
      xlabel={$n$}, x label style={anchor=north},
      ylabel={$x[n]$}, y label style={anchor=west}]
      \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] plot coordinates
      {(-1,1) (0,2) (1,1)};
      \node[anchor=south west] at (axis cs:0,2) {$2$};
      \node[anchor=south east] at (axis cs:-1,1) {$1$};
      \node[anchor=south west] at (axis cs:1,1) {$1$};
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}%
      \hspace*{3mm} {\Huge\pointer} \hspace*{3mm}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
        every label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
      \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
        xticklabels={{}, {}, {}, 0, 1, 2, 3},
        extra x ticks={-2,-1},
        extra x tick labels={$-3$,$-2$,$-1$},
        extra x tick style={
          xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south}},
        xmin=-4,xmax=4, ytick={\empty}, yticklabels={}, 
        ymin=-2, ymax=2, axis on top,
        enlarge y limits=0.35,
        width=6cm,
        xlabel={$n$}, x label style={anchor=north},
        ylabel={$y[n]$}, y label style={anchor=west}]
        \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] plot coordinates
        {(-3,0) (-2,-1) (-1,-2) (0,0) (1,2) (2,1) (3,0)};
        \node[anchor=north] at (axis cs:-2,-1) {$-1$};
        \node[anchor=north] at (axis cs:-1,-2) {$-2$};
        \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:1,2) {$2$};
        \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:2,1) {$1$};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\tikzset{font=\tiny}` to your preamble to make it work. But of course then this applies to *all* TikZ text you write in your document (except at the places where a style overwrites this setting of course).

Comment: @StefanPinnow Add it inside the `figure`, and the setting will be local.

Comment: Thanks.  \tikzset{font=\tiny} works. However, the fontsize of x[n] and y[n] also becomes tiny, which is to be expected, I guess.   Suppose I want only to the stem labels to change, is that possible in a global setting (without affecting x[n] and y[n]) ?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., of course. I just provided in the comment *one* possibility. Yours is another. A third would be to move the already defined style `every label` to another place and use/apply it, e.g. at the beginning of the `figure` environment instead of `font=tiny` directly ...

Comment: @CSR, of course, but then the title of your question would be misleading. Please restate your question accordingly by editing it. Be as precise as possible what you want to achieve.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I now realize that the title is misleading. Scratching my head on how to modify it appropriately.  I did see quite a few posts in this forum on how to change size of labels associated with nodes, which led me to try "every label./style" statement, which wasn't quite working as I had thought it would (due to my poor understanding).  "How to change label font size" is a question that has been already asked. May be I should delete the question? Please advice, as I am a newbie.  Thanks.

Comment: @CSR, not a problem. We all started as newbies ;) To the deletion of the question: that depends; if your *real* question is answered in that question, you can delete this question, yes. Otherwise please do what I already stated: edit your question and be as precise as possible. You can also link to other questions which are similar but didn't work in your case. That all helps us, the helpers, but also other people searching for a similar question which don't know how to formulate the question "properly", by that I mean that they just don't know it more precise.

Comment: @CSR, if you want to learn something more, you could also reformulate your question to: "Why isn't my `every label/.style` showing `tiny` nodes?".

Comment: @TorbjørnT., sorry, was in a hurry so didn't want to wait with my comment. So then I'll delete my comment to your deleted comment, too ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow I think your suggested title captures my problem much better.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has various causes, but the main reason is, that you don't *have* any "label nodes" in the sense of TikZ. Label nodes are nodes that are applied to nodes itself like `\node [label=above:I am a label node] {I am the main node};`. The nodes you are using are just "regular" nodes.

Said that you can come to idea to then state e.g. `every node/.append style={font=\tiny,green}` (in the `\tikzset`), but because *everything* that contains some text is a node, that would be way more then you want. Give it a try to see what happens.

I allowed myself to modify your MWE a bit and reordered some stuff. Then I commented everything that is "a bit strange"/"not straight-forward", just in case you also want to learn some other stuff besides the "tiny node" question.

If you should only be interested in the "tiny node stuff", search for the blocks that are surrounded by dashed lines.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% one possibility to show tiny labels is to define a new style which you
% apply later to the corresponding nodes
\tikzset{
    Label/.style={
        font=\tiny,
        red,
    },
}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\pgfplotsset{
%    % this (whole) style isn't *used* in the following tikzpictures/axis
%    % environments so it isn't needed here
%    standard/.style={%Axis format configuration
%        axis x line=middle,
%        axis y line=middle,
%        enlarge x limits=0.15,
%        enlarge y limits=0.15,
%        every label/.style={font=\tiny},
%        every axis x label/.style={
%            at={(current axis.right of origin)},
%            anchor=north west,
%        },
%        every axis y label/.style={
%            at={(current axis.above origin)},
%            anchor=north east,
%        },
%        every axis plot post/.style={
%            mark options={fill=black},
%        },
%    },
%}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%    % in this case this statement is not needed
%    baseline=(current bounding box.center),
]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xtick={-1,0,1},
%        % you don't need this, because the tick labels are identical to the ticks
%        xticklabels={-1, 0, 1},
%        % there are no `extra x ticks` so you don't need this as well
%        extra x tick style={
%            xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south},
%        },
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=4,
        ytick={\empty},
%        % since you don't state `ytick's you don't to provide corresponding labels ...
%        yticklabels={},
        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
        axis on top,
        enlarge y limits=0.35,
        width=6cm,
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={$x[n]$},
        x label style={anchor=north},
        y label style={anchor=west},
    ]
        \addplot+ [ycomb,black,thick] coordinates {
            (-1,1) (0,2) (1,1)
        };
        \node [anchor=south west] at (axis cs:0,2)  {$2$};
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % as stated earlier there are plenty of ways to achieve what you want
        % to do, here are some possibilities
        %
        % 1. provide what you need directly to the node
        \node [
            anchor=south east,
            font=\tiny,
            red,
        ] at (axis cs:-1,1) {$1$};
        % 2. apply the created style directly to the node
        \node [
            anchor=south west,
            Label,
        ] at (axis cs:1,1)  {$1$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
%    baseline=(current bounding box.center),
]
        \pgfplotsset{
            every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
%            % this style is a TikZ style for "labels of nodes" and not nodes that are labels,
%            % that is why you don't see any changing font sizes
%            % said that, it is also not needed here
%            every label/.append style={font=\tiny},
        }
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
        % as you can see the zero isn't shown, although you stated it here
        % this is because of the key `hide obscured x ticks' which is true by default when
        % `axis lines' are set to `middle' or the alias `center'
        xticklabels={{}, {}, {}, 0, 1, 2, 3},
        % also this is strange. You state the ticks at positions -2 and -1, ...
        extra x ticks={-2,-1},
        % ... but apply the numbers -3 and -2 to them. Is that intended?
        extra x tick labels={$-3$,$-2$,$-1$},
        extra x tick style={
            xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex,anchor=south}, },
        xmin=-4, xmax=4,
        ytick={\empty},
        yticklabels={},
        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
        axis on top,
        enlarge y limits=0.35,
        width=6cm,
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={$y[n]$},
        x label style={anchor=north},
        y label style={anchor=west},
    ]
        \addplot+ [ycomb,black,thick] plot coordinates
            {(-3,0) (-2,-1) (-1,-2) (0,0) (1,2) (2,1) (3,0)
        };
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % 3. but you could also scope the nodes and apply the style of the
        %    nodes
        \begin{scope}[
            font=\tiny,
            red,
        ]
            \node [anchor=north] at (axis cs:-2,-1) {$-1$};
            \node [anchor=north] at (axis cs:-1,-2) {$-2$};
        \end{scope}
        % 3. or of course apply the style in the scope
        \begin{scope}[
            Label,
        ]
            \node [anchor=west]  at (axis cs:1,2)   {$2$};
            \node [anchor=west]  at (axis cs:2,1)   {$1$};
        \end{scope}
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to explain.  Greatly appreciated!